# Subsets of real space and subspaces

Tags: geometry

These are the following subsets of real space $\Bbb R^3$ :

1) $\{(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in \Bbb R^3:  x_2,x_3 = 0\}$

2) $\{(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in \Bbb R^3:  x_2-x_3+2x_1 = 0\}$

3) $\{(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in \Bbb R^3: x_3 ≤ x_2 ≤ x_1 \}$

How many of them are subspaces of $\Bbb R^3$ ?

What is real space $\Bbb R^3$ ? How these sub sets are related?

Just cannot guess anything.Help please.

Comment: I fixed up the formatting.  Please check that this is what you intended.

Comment: By *subspace* do you mean *linear subspace*?  What is your definition of subspace?

Comment: @Sammy Oops, it seems I edited over you by accident. Sorry.

Comment: @SammyBlack i don't know, just came across in the list of question bank.No idea..

Comment: try to draw them. intuitively, ask yourself if the drawn space satsifies the three conditions. (1) it contains the origin. (2) you can add vectors. (3) you can scale vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the following number systems:

- The natural numbers: $\mathbb{N}=\{1, 2, 3, \dots\}$
- The integers: $\mathbb{Z}=\{0, \pm 1, \pm 2, \dots\}$
- The rationals: $\mathbb{Q}=\{\frac{p}{q}\vert p\in\mathbb{Z}, q\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}\}$ - these are numbers that can be written as fractions.
- The irrationals: $\{\sqrt 2, \pi, e, \dots\}$, these are numbers that cannot be written as fractions so this set is the complement of the rationals.

  From the above we think of the real numbers as the union of the rationals and the irrationals and denote it as $\mathbb{R}$, so every element in the reals is either a rational number or an irrational number.
  The above sets are related as follows:
  \begin{equation}
  \mathbb{N}\subset\mathbb{Z}\subset\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{Q}\cup\{\text{irrationals}\}.
  \end{equation}
  You will be familiar with the number line. This is a 'graphical' represention of the reals and we write it as an interval $(-\infty, \infty)$.

If I take three copies of the reals it's like I am taking three number lines and putting  them up at right angles as we see in the cartesian coordinate system. These three copies  of $\mathbb{R}$ ie, $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ is denoted as $\mathbb{R}^3$. An element of this set is written as $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ where each $x_i\in\mathbb{R}$.

A subset $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a vector subspace if it contains the zero element ie. $(0, 0, 0)\in V $, if it is closed under addition (so if $a=(a_1, a_2, a_3), b=(b_1, b_2, b_3)\in V$ then $a+b=(a_1+b_1,a_2+b_2, a_3+b_3) \in V$),  and if it is closed under scalar multiplication (so if $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}, v=(v_1, v_2, v_3)\in V$ then $\alpha v=(\alpha v_1, \alpha v_2, \alpha v_3)\in V$.

You can now check if each of the sets you have given satisfy these three conditions or not. If they do then they are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$, otherwise they are not.

Your last question is quite vague. If it turns out that all three subsets are vector subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$ I guess this would mean that they are related in that sense.

Comment: Another hint the first two subsets are vector subspaces but the last one isn't. The last one fails to be closed under scalar multiplication

Comment: It is NOT true that $\mathbb{N}\subset\mathbb{Z}\subset\mathbb{Q}\subset\{\text{irrationals}\}\subset\mathbb{R}$
Rational numbers set are not in irrational numbers set, in fact they are disjoint.
But you wrote well, it's just that expression.

Comment: @AarónDavidArroyoTorres Woops! Thanks for letting me know. I have edited my answer appropriately.